# Integer Vector element comparison using subscript operator fails, but succeeds using at function

Tags: c++, windows, api, stl, vector

I am writing a callback function which has a reference to a int vector passed to it in a structure. When I try to access an element in the vector using subscript operator[], Intellisense indicates that the == cannot compare the two elements specifically the error is 
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion). But when using at() function there is no problem.

```
//body of call back function
searchInfo* argVal = (searchInfo*) Parameter;
for(int i = argVal->inclStartPos; i < argVal->exclEndPos; ++i){
    if(argVal->numVector[i] == argVal->searchNum)//problem here
        argVal->result = true;
//this is the structure passed through pointer

struct searchInfo{
int inclStartPos;
int exclEndPos;
vector<int>* numVector; 
int searchNum;
bool result;
};
```

Since the [] operator and at() function of a vector work almost(the difference doesn't matter here) in the same manner, why the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you are comparing vector < int > with int, since the field numVector has type

```
vector<int>*
```

Simply speaking, you've declared an array of vector's.
Operator [] will return a value of type vector.

Probably you have misspelled the declaration. Maybe you wanted to declare numVector as follows:

```
vector<int> numVector;
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It may not be expressed as clearly as possible, but it's right - `numVector` is a pointer-to-vector, which is compatible with array-of-vector. Hence `numVector[i]` is a `vector<int>`; but `numVector->at(i)` would work.

Comment: @Chowlett: Could you please elaborate on why would numVector->at(i) would work.
AFAIK the '==' operator has same data types on both sides , so the expression should work but it doesn't.

Comment: @AquaAsh - `numVector` is a _pointer_, not an actual vector. Hence `numVector[i]` will be interpreted as subscripting into an array `vector<int>[]` from the address `numVector`, not as taking an element from a `vector<int>`. `numVector[i] == searchNum` compares `vector<int>` with `int`.`numVector->at(i)` is calling `at` on the object pointed to by `numVector` - it's equivalent to `*numVector.at(i)`